# android 4.0 video streaming

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Is there any easy way in Android 4.0 ICS to stream video from the camera to an other phone? Especially with API functions.

If not, can you show me an example how to capture the camera stream into the memory and send it via UDP. (ex. FileDescriptor?)

Thanks for the anwsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can have MediaRecorder write the stream to a socket instead of a file but none of the selectable container formats works for streaming.
They all have headers that are written after the recording is done.
MPEG2-TS is not officially supported and doesn't work on nearly all devices.

No idea how the ustream -app does it.